# TCL, getmac.exe not found from within script

Tags: cygwin, tcl

I have a script that contains the following passage:

```
switch -exact $OS {
    "Windows" {
        # Get the path to getmac.exe
        set path [exec which getmac]
        # Run getmac.exe to get the MAC address
        set mac_addr [exec $path.exe /fo table /nh]
        # Extract the last six characters, which are the MAC address
        set mac_addr [string range $mac_addr end-16 end-1]
    }
    default {
        # Get the MAC address on Linux
        set mac_addr [exec "ifconfig | grep ether | head -n1 | awk '{print \$2}'"]
        # Extract the last five characters, which are the MAC address
        set mac_addr [string range $mac_addr end-4 end-1]
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error

```
*couldn't execute "'\cygdrive\c\WINDOWS\system32\getmac.exe": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec '$path.exe /fo table /nh'"
    ("Windows" arm line 5)
    invoked from within
"switch -exact $OS {
    "Windows" {
        # Get the path to getmac.exe
        set path [exec which getmac]
        # Run getmac.exe to get the MAC ..."*
```

To me it looks as if it does not find the getmac executable.
However, if i just run getmac in the console window, it finds and executes it.

I'm in a cygwin environment for Intel FPGAs which runs TCL 8.6
It is somehow apparent that also the script finds the path to the executable, because I ask it for the path in the first place. Since the error message displays the correct path to getmac, I wonder why it is not able to execute or "find" the file....

I also tried

```
set mac_addr [exec '$path.exe /fo table /nh']
```

and

```
set mac_addr [exec "$path.exe /fo table /nh"]
```

What can I do, to make this work from within a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec which getmac` is returning an answer like this:

```
'\cygdrive\c\WINDOWS\system32\getmac.exe'
```

The main thing to note: that result is *single quoted* and Tcl does not understand `'` characters to be anything other than simple characters.

In theory, you could write code to decode the result, but there really is no point; Tcl provides `auto_execok` in its standard library that does the same sort of task:

```
switch -exact $OS {
    "Windows" {
        # Run getmac.exe to get the MAC address
        set mac_addr [exec {*}[auto_execok getmac] /fo table /nh]
        # Extract the last six characters, which are the MAC address
        set mac_addr [string range $mac_addr end-16 end-1]
    }
    default {
        # Get the MAC address on Linux
        set mac_addr [exec ifconfig | grep ether | head -n1 | awk {{print $2}}]
        # Extract the last five characters, which are the MAC address
        set mac_addr [string range $mac_addr end-4 end-1]
    }
}
```

I also fixed your Linux version somewhat. But the MAC address really isn't ever going to be 4 or 5 characters long...

Comment: Thank you very much! Also for the additional explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`autoexec_ok`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm#M6):

```
exec {*}[auto_execok getmac] /fo table /nh
```

Comment: same for your branch using `ifconfig` btw